# How to Add a new Event from eventReceived on fullCalendar with jquery

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I want to be able to add a new event when a dragged element is dropped on a calendar day and certain conditions are met. I notice that when the element is placed on a day, the `eventReceived` of fullCalendar is executed; so I made use of the `calendar.addEvent` method however, then when making a console.log of the events with `.getEvents` it is still not added and it is not rendered in the calendar.

[image]

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As per [ask] please do not include images of your code. Code is text and must be included in your question as text. You can [edit] your post to update it, and then it will be easier for us to help you. Thanks.

Comment: P.S. The documentation is clear that `eventReceive` runs _after_ an event has _already been automatically added_ to the calendar. So you don't need to call `addEvent` in that situation - the event should be already placed on the calendar, in the area it was dragged to. If it isn't there, check the browser's console for any error messages. https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventReceive